# CodeIgniter 2 - Display 404 Page Only When User is Authenicated

Tags: codeigniter, codeigniter-2

I have a CodeIgniter 2 app that currently returns a 404 page anytime an user requests an invalid URL.  Inside my **MY_controller.php** file, I have a function that checks whether the user is authenticated.  If the URL the user requested is valid and the user is not logged in, they are redirected to the login page.  If the URL they requested is invalid, they'll see a 404 page whether or not they are logged in.

If the user is not logged in, is there anyway to redirect the user to the log in page even when they request an invalid URL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes possible. steps given below

1. Create a new controller named `Errors` in your controllers directory with following code

   ```
   defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

    class Errors extends CI_Controller {

      public function index() {
       redirect('authentication/login');
      }

   }
   ```
2. Now in your `config/routes.php` file `$route['404_override']` change as following

   ```
   $route['404_override'] = 'errors/index';
   ```

Now you will be redirected when wrong URL given instead showing 404 error page

3. If you want logged in user will see 404 error but NOT LOGGED IN user will see login page then change your `index` method in `Errors` controller as

   ```
    public function index() {
      if($this->session->userdata('user_id')){// check any session item
          show_404();
      }
      redirect('authentication/login');
    }
   ```

Comment: This led me in the right direction.  I also have a function in `MY_Controller` called `security_check()` that checks whether a user is authenticated or not.  It seems CodeIgniter will always run the 404 page check first (in your example this would be the `errors/index` function) before running the `security_check()` function.  Is there anyway to get CodeIgniter to reverse the logic here and run `security_check()` before checking whether the page exists?

Comment: you may call `security_check()` in place of `$this->session->userdata('user_id')`